# 2-step user registration with Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm creating a website with Django and want a fairly common 2-step user registration.  What I mean by this is that the user fills in the some basic user information + some application specific information (sort of like a coupon value).  Upon submit, an email is sent to ensure email address is valid.  This email should contain a link to click on to "finish" the registration.  When the link is clicked, the user is marked as validated and they are directed to a new page to complete optional "user profile" type information.

So, pretty basic stuff.  I have done some research and found django-registration by James Bennett.  I do know who James is and have seen him at PyCons and DjanoCons in the past.  There is obviously very few people in the world that know Django better than James (so, I know the quality of the code/app is good).  But, it almost seems like a bit of over kill.  I've read through the docs and was a bit confused (maybe I'm just being a bit dense today).  I believe that if I do use django-registration, I will need to have some custom forms, etc.

Is there anything else out there I should evaluate?  Or are there any good tutorials or videos on using django-registration?  I've done a bit of googling, but haven't found anything.  But, I suspect that it might be a case of a lot of very common words that don't really find what you are looking for (django user registration tutorial/example).

Or is just a case where it would be just about as easy to build your own solution with Django forms, etc?

Here is the tech stack I'm using:

```
Python 2.7.2 
Django 1.3.1
PostgreSQL 9.1
psycopg2 2.4.1
Twitter Bootstrap 2.0.2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

django-registration is actually pretty easy to get going, though depending on which docs you're looking at it can seem kind of overwhelming. Are you looking at [the quickstart guide](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/27bccd108cde/docs/quickstart.rst)?

All you really need to do is install it, add one line each to your settings and urls.py, and make a few templates. I think there are probably better example templates out there, but [here are the ones for an old project of mine](https://github.com/daily-gazette/gazjango/tree/master/gazjango/templates/registration).

That project used the approach of putting profile info in the original registration form, which meant making [a simple subclass of RegistrationForm](https://github.com/daily-gazette/gazjango/blob/master/gazjango/accounts/forms.py), making a [small registration backend](https://github.com/daily-gazette/gazjango/blob/master/gazjango/accounts/registration_backends.py), and [hacking that into the registration urls](https://github.com/daily-gazette/gazjango/blob/master/gazjango/accounts/registration_urls.py). (There might well be a better way to do this now; I originally wrote this 4 years ago and haven't touched it in 2 years. But this works and isn't very hard.)

You can then redirect to fill out option user profile info either by adding a link to the activation_complete page, or probably more directly by changing some settings in django-registration that I don't know offhand.

Comment: Thank you Dougal.  I appreciate the help.  I have looked at your project.  I think this will be helpful.

Comment: That's awesome, I'm going to be trying this out today. It's amazing what a well-defined package from 2008 can do! :o

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [Pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/) as it tries to simplify all boiler plate aspects of a website.